# Moment object won't increment by days when cloned and used with DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, datetimepicker

I have the following code:

```
  function localDateHandler(momentObj) {


      let start = momentObj.clone();
      let update = start.add(10, 'days');

      console.log(update);    // Does not change, SHOULD be ten days more than momentObj
      console.log(momentObj);

}
```

I am using the following React component to change the date:

```
 <DateTimePicker value={eventDate} onChange={localDateHandler}/>
```

The info for the component is here: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/

When I change the date the date is not incremented by the number of days listed in the first block of code (I explain more in the comments)

Thank you!

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (could be on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce and this works with not any problem. What you have seen maybe caused by one of these case:

- You might have briefly looked at `_i` of moment object, this might be the initial object (which could derive from `momentObj.clone()`), instead, you should look `_d` instead ([moment object internal properties doc](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/))

  > The most commonly viewed internal property is the `_d` property that holds the JavaScript Date that Moment wrappers.
- You might not have use the right version of peer dependency for moment adapter ([installation guide](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation))

  > **Important**: For material-ui-pickers v3 use **v1.x** version of @date-io adapters.

Codesandbox for demonstration, you should open the log to check

[image: Edit frosty-mcnulty-wu5s1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JS code works as it should (the comment is clearly false):

```js
function localDateHandler(momentObj) {

      let start = momentObj.clone();
      let update = start.add(10, 'days');

      console.log(update);    // Does not change, SHOULD be ten days more than momentObj
      console.log(momentObj);

}

localDateHandler(moment());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Yields in my case:

```
"2020-08-24T22:29:35.347Z"
"2020-08-14T22:29:35.347Z"
```

I'm guessing something wrong with rendering? Then I suspect you'd have to modify `eventDate` somewhere in `localDateHandler`, not some local variable not bound to the widget.